# Simple Accordion syntax

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-animate

I am trying to figure why the nav links wont open the accordion. I am sure there is just some jquery that is not in proper syntax. I changed the selectors in the jquery code and now it wont work.

Im sure to a trained eye this should be a quick fix.

Can anyone help?

////////////////////////////
    // http://www.adipalaz.com/experiments/jquery/accordion.html
    ///////////////////////////
    (function($) {
    //http://www.mail-archive.com/jquery-en@googlegroups.com/msg43851.html
    $.fn.orphans = function(){
        var txt = [];
        this.each(function(){$.each(this.childNodes, function() {
            if (this.nodeType == 3 && $.trim(this.nodeValue)) txt.push(this)
        })}); 
        return $(txt);
    };
    //http://www.learningjquery.com/2008/02/simple-effects-plugins:
    $.fn.fadeToggle = function(speed, easing, callback) {
        return this.animate({opacity: 'toggle'}, speed, easing, callback);
    };
    $.fn.slideFadeToggle = function(speed, easing, callback) {
        return this.animate({opacity: 'toggle', height: 'toggle'}, speed, easing, callback);
    };
    })(jQuery);
    ////////////////////////////
    $(function() {
        $('.collapse').hide(); 
        $('.expand').orphans().wrap('');



        //demo 4 - div.demo:eq(3) - queued slide effects:
        $('div.demo .expand').click(function() {
            var $thisCllps = $(this).next('.collapse');
            var $cllpsVisible = $(this).ul('.expand').next('.collapse:visible');
            ($cllpsVisible.length) ? $(this).toggleClass('open').siblings('.expand').removeClass('open')
                .next('.collapse:visible').slideUp(400, function() {
                $thisCllps.slideDown();
                }) : $thisCllps.slideToggle().prev('.expand').toggleClass('open');
            return false;
        });


    });

```
    <div class="demo">


        <ul class="collapse" class="ul" style="display: none; ">
          <li>Item 1.1.</li>    
          <li>Item 1.2.</li>
        </ul>

        <ul class="collapse" class="ul" style="display: none; ">
          <li>Item 2.1.</li>    
          <li>Item 2.2.</li>
        </ul>

        <ul class="collapse" class="ul" style="display: none; ">
          <li>Item 3.1.</li>    
          <li>Item 3.2.</li>
        </ul>
    </div>
<ul>
<li>
    <h4 class="expand"><a href="#" title="expand/collapse">Slide Up/Down UL 1</a></h4>
</li>
<li>
    <h4 class="expand"><a href="#" title="expand/collapse">Slide Up/Down UL 2</a></h4>
</li>
<li>
    <h4 class="expand"><a href="#" title="expand/collapse">Slide Up/Down UL 3</a></h4>
</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: There are no elements matching `.expand` inside your `.demo` `<div>`.

Comment: I just tried to fix that, but it still doesnt work. I also changed a couple of things see my link. See anything else?http://dl.dropbox.com/u/14080718/Final/SimpleAccordion.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why not just use the Jquery accordion function?

http://docs.jquery.com/UI/Accordion

Comment: I would, but I need to activate the accordion with links that are in a list and would not be in the same div. I also need to have each accordion pane completely shut before another opens. Just like in this example http://dl.dropbox.com/u/14080718/Final/NeedHelp2.html (fyi: I cant use this code because I need to panes to be fluid) If you know how to make UI do this stuff, I would love to use it.

Comment: You inspired this question. Love for you to take a look. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8856939/jquery-ui-accordion-modification